# 2 Win10 on same machine on different HDDs - can the other be started as a VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I have a dualboot system where both OS (2 x Win10) are on different HDDs.

I would like to know if it is possible when I boot into the first OS that I can some how start the second OS as a VM, without sacrificing the dualboot functionality, both OS should stay intact and can be booted normally.

Comment: You'd like to have an OS be capable of booting both as a VM AND as its own physical machine?

Comment: @music2myear yes, thats basically what I am asking

Comment: While you can run the same windows license twice in a dual boot configuration, that's not the case when one is in a vm. Even when you have two licenses one may get lost converting p2v due to differing (virtual) hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VM runs on virtual hardware which is not the same as the physical hardware it is running on top of.

While modern Windows OSes don't have too much trouble jumping hardware from a driver point of view, they DO have trouble jumping that much hardware from a licensing point of view.

Further, there is a process call Physical to Virtual (P2V) that is required when converting a physical machine to a virtual machine. There is also a V2P process for those times you'd need to move a system the other way. Neither of these are quick processes, and they usually require several hours of work.

So, while it is technically possible to to this, it would be far from an on-demand process. It would take hours of conversion time between each mode, and there's no guarantee it would work reliably.

What you should be asking yourself is why you have two Windows 10 machines and why you need this particular configuration. Personally, I'd just run one in a VM permanently. Then when I need it I can spin it up and work in it, and when I want more resources on the host I could just pause the VM and free up its resources.

Comment: The main reason is performance for both OS. I want 100% performance and dont get hit by limitations of free VM software. Sad that its not working. I hoped since VM software are capable to use a physical drive, I thought maybe its possible to use it on-demand way.